# Intellij Idea, open new project creates a new tab for each project, how do I revert to a default of a new window per open project?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

If I open a new project in Intellij Idea it now opens it as a new tab.  How to change the default behaviour, revert to the previous behaviour and open in a new window?

Comment: macOS System Preferences->General set "Prefer tabs when opening documents" to "Never".

Comment: I think that's a macOS setting, this seems to be IntelliJ that is doing it

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is using macOS setting right now. There is a request to have IDE specific setting.

Comment: Unless I've got something wrong, Intellij Idea is causing this behaviour, not MacOS (you can see the tabs are even in the same dark mode setting managed by IntelliJ).  I'd like to turn this off in IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is causing this behavior by respecting the mentioned macOS system preference, see the related tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260522
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65293
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2893.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am sorry, you are right!  It is a macOS preference that is causing this.  Many apologies!  Setting to 'Never' as you say seems to fix this.  That's all I needed (i thought that setting was for a new full screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In macOS System Preferences | General, set "**Prefer tabs when opening documents**" to "**Never**".

Related documents and tickets:

- macOS User Guide: [Use tabs in windows on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-tabs-in-windows-mchla4695cce/mac)
- [Big Sur: Add support of opening project as tabs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2893)
- [Open project in a new window opens in a tab instead](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260522)
- [View multiple IntelliJ IDEA projects in a single frame](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65293)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - select Help | Find Action from the main menu, type Registry..., select it and in the opened list, find and disable the ide.mac.transparentTitleBarAppearance (just start typing to search it) options here, restart the IDE to see whether it helps

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291007/opening-multiple-projects-in-tabs-stopped-working